# Not able to run this view function in python using flask framework

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.name.data).first()
        if user is None:
            user = User(username=form.name.data)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            session['known'] = False
        else:
            session['known'] = True
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template("index1.html", form=form, name=session.get('name'), known=session.get('known', False))
```

While running the following program once I am submitting the form its getting internal server error. Please help me in this, really struggling hard to rectify this.

Comment: Are you using `app.run(debug=True)`?

Comment: It's not a good idea to develop with disabled error messages (actually it's completely wrong). There is no way to fix it, if you don't know what to fix (you don't know the error message). So start with enabling the error reporting and add an error message it's producing into your question.

Comment: I ran the server in debug mode and able to solve my problem...Thanks a lot...